# Could not get Value from RatingBar in Alert Dialog

Tags: java, android, ratingbar

i've got a alertdialog which shows rating bar.

```
LayoutInflater rating = LayoutInflater.from(RatingActivity.this);
            final View v = rating.inflate(R.layout.rating_layout, null);

            AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(RatingActivity.this);
            adb.setTitle("Rate us!);
            adb.setView(v);
            AlertDialog ratingbar = adb.create();

final RatingBar cleanbar = (RatingBar) ratingbar.findViewById(R.id.clealiness);
```

when I triggered onclick listener, it shows NULL POINTER EXCEPTION. and 2nd line error says error in getNumStars() line.. Force close after that.

```
adb.setPositiveButton("Rate", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
    //this line error. means they cant get the rating value?
final String cleaninput = Integer.toString(cleanbar.getNumStars());
```

may i know any other ways to get the value of ratingbar? i've seen few like ratingBar.getRating();  ratingBar.getNumStars();

all of them could not work... even i put the value direct into int.

```
final int cleaninput = (int) cleanbar.getRating();  //fails
```

EDITTED (SOLVE)::

```
final RatingBar cleanbar = (RatingBar)v.findViewById(R.id.clealiness);
```

i replace the ratingbar to v instead and it works! i do not know the reason >.<

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is this:

```
final RatingBar cleanbar = (RatingBar) ratingbar.findViewById(R.id.clealiness);
```

It won't initialise correctly RatingBar because you are not initialising RatingBar from layout of Activity(that contains RatingBar) and this is reason why you get **`NPE`** at

```
cleanbar.getNumStars() // cleanbar is assigned as null
```

Change it to

```
final RatingBar cleanbar = (RatingBar) findViewById(R.id.clealiness);
```

Now it should work.

### Update:

```
LayoutInflater rating = LayoutInflater.from(RatingActivity.this);
final View ratingView = rating.inflate(R.layout.rating_layout, null);

AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(RatingActivity.this);               
adb.setTitle("Rate us!);
adb.setView(ratingView);

AlertDialog ratingbar = adb.create();
```

Now for getting value correctly:

```
RatingBar cleanbar = (RatingBar) ratingView.findViewById(R.id.clealiness);
```

You need to assign `RatingBar` with `View` you inflated.

Now it should works:

```
final int cleaninput = (int) cleanbar.getRating();
```

Comment: yes, i did inflate to other view, and the alertdialog in inflater of mine is rating.bar =(

Comment: @PolarBear you need to init. your RatingBar as i mentioned. RatingBar is contained in layout that you are setting with setContentView(R.layout.idLayout) and this method creates all instances of UI elements contained in layout so you need to use `RatingBar cleanbar = (RatingBar) findViewById(R.id.clealiness);` not your approach.

Comment: i see.. but i tried the way you guide me. no luck :( i editted the latest one in post..

Comment: yup. Thanks for helping me! its view instead of AlertDialog.